# Aligning a Lower-Dimensional Object With A Plane

Tags: geometry, rotations, computational-geometry

Given an n-1 dimensional simplex in n-dimensional space (at an unknown rotation), I am looking for a way align the object with a given plane, i.e. rotate it in such a way that the coordinates for that plane are all 0.

For example, a triangle in 3d might have the following vertices:

<sub>\begin{align*}
A &= (1,0,0) \\
B &= (0,1,0) \\
C &= (0,0,1)
\end{align*}</sub>

Given the y-plane for instance, I would like to rotate this triangle so that the y-coordinates of all vertices are 0, while maintaining shape.

The concept extends to higher dimensions, for instance aligning a tetrahedron in 4d. Unfortunately, I have not found a method to achieve this, or even a way to determine the original rotation of a lower-dimensional object from the vertices alone.

If anyone knows of how to do this or has a general outline it would be very much appreciated.